# How to pass implicit value to a function?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, implicits

I am new to `scala`. I am learning `implicit variables`. How can a pass an implicit variable to a function that calls another function that is gonna use that variable. I know this question seems stupid. Just look at the code that I have written.

```
class Person{

    def whoAmI(implicit name: String): Unit = {
        println(s"I am $name")
    }
}

class NewPerson{
    def whoAmI: Unit = {
        val p: Person = new Person
        p.whoAmI
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    implicit val name: String = "a Shamir"
    val person: NewPerson = new NewPerson
    person.whoAmI
}
```

This code doesn't work. But this does.

```
class Person{

    def whoAmI(implicit name: String): Unit = {
        println(s"I am $name")
    }
}

class NewPerson{
    implicit val name: String = "a Shamir"
    def whoAmI: Unit = {
        val p: Person = new Person
        p.whoAmI
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    val person: NewPerson = new NewPerson
    person.whoAmI
}
```

I want something like this.

```
class Person{

    def whoAmI(implicit name: String): Unit = {
        println(s"I am $name")
    }
}

class NewPerson{
    def whoAmI: Unit = {
        val p: Person = new Person
        p.whoAmI
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    implicit val name: String = "a Shamir"
    val person: NewPerson = new NewPerson
    person.whoAmI()(name)
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should pick a more refined type for implicits, having a primitive as an implicit is not very neat. A `String` or `Int` implicit is ALWAYS a bad idea in production code. Now you are learning so it's good to get used to this.

So let's say we have:

```
case class Name(name: String)
```

Now it's important to understand implicit propagation and forwarding. Implicits propagate through either inheritance or higher scope, so you either extend something that has the implicit you are looking for or you import it in a higher scope.

It's also best to define implicits in the secound group of function params, like this:

```
def test(p1: T1, p2: T2..)(implicit ev1: E1, ev2: E2): ReturnType = {}
```

This is because when you call the function `whoAmI` with parantheses, the compiler expects the implicit passed explicitly, which voids the very point of using implicits.

So when you write the `whoAmI` lik this:

```
def whoAmI(implicit name: Name): Unit
```

And you call like this: `whoAmI()` with the `()`, compiler is expecting you to pass the name manually. Implicits are "hidden", meaning that once defined they are meant to be "just there", so long as you abide scoping rules they are used to eliminate typing boilerplate.

```
class Person {

    def whoAmI()(implicit name: Name): Unit = {
        println(s"I am ${name.name}")
    }
}

class NewPerson {
    // Here your implicit is mising
    def whoAmI()(implicit name: Name): Unit = {
        val p: Person = new Person
        p.whoAmI
    }
}

object Main extends App {
    implicit val name: Name = Name("a Shamir")
    val person: NewPerson = new NewPerson
    // Now you don't actually need to manually type in the implicit
    person.whoAmI()
}
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the Person and the NewPerson class as it is? Then is it possible?

Comment: @eddard.stark, no because when you call `whoAmi` in the `NewPerson` class on the person object you haven't told the compiler where to get the implicit from. You can do something like `class NewPerson()(implicit ev: Name) {..}`, e.g put the implicit in the constructor, but you need to provide it somehow.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without changing only `NewPerson`?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify, that NewPerson.whoAmI takes implicit parameter and it'll be used in Person.whoAmI

```
 class Person {

    def whoAmI(implicit name: String): Unit = {
      println(s"I am $name")
    }
  }

  class NewPerson {
    def whoAmI()(implicit name: String): Unit = {
      val p: Person = new Person
      p.whoAmI
    }
  }

  object Main extends App {    
    implicit val name: String = "a Shamir"
    val person: NewPerson = new NewPerson
    person.whoAmI()(name)
  }
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the Person and the NewPerson class as it is? Then is it possible?